# Include part of older version of committed file in new committed version of file

Tags: git, github

My question concerns git and how to use it properly. My knowledge is very basic.

I accidentally deleted a code chunk in my file, but only realized this after committing and pushing to github.
Before realizing, I made additional intentional changes which I also committed and pushed.
Now, I want to include the uninentionally deleted code chunk in the most recent (committed) version of my file.

(How) is that possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already pushed your commit, altering it is potentially dangerous, since someone might have checked it out and is now working on top of it. It would be cleaner to add the chunk in a new commit.

It is, however, possible to acquire the chunk of code and include it in the most recent version of your file, but you will have to create new commits one way or the other.

You did not mention if you use any kind of GUI, so I will assume you use git by command line.

Option 1: To add it as a new commit on top of your old commit, use your tool of choice to show your repos history (this would be gitk on the command line), find the pre-previous commit, copy the chunk that has been deleted, paste it in your current code and commit and push the newly added chunk.

Option 2: To go back in your repositorys history and change the deletion in the first place, you can use

```
git reset HEAD~2
```

to reset your repository back by two commits. The changes introduced by your two commits now appear als unstaged changes in your working directory. To revert the deletion of the chunk you want to keep, you can either undo your changes in the whole file (if there are no other changes) by

```
git checkout -- <filename>
```

or undo just the deletion of the chunk by

```
git checkout -p <filename>
```

and following on-screen instructions. Then, you can commit your changes, either as one commit or seperated in two, as they were initally. When you want to push, you will have to force overwrite with the --force argument, since your history differs from the one upstream. Be aware that THIS IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE.